# compiling emberjs complains about phantomjs on windows 7

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs

I'm trying to compile emberjs but everytime i run `rake` it keeps telling me

```
Building Ember...
Done
The system cannot find the path specified.
PhantomJS is not installed. Download from http://phantomjs.org
```

I downloaded PhantomJS and extracted it to `C:\Program Files\phantomjs-1.7.0-windows` and I added this path to my environment and system PATH.

When I open a command prompt and I run phantomjs --version I get 1.7.0 but if I run rake to compile ember it keeps complaining phantomjs is not installed.

What else needs to be done for phantomjs to be 'detected'?

Comment: I wonder isn't the cause this line in `rakefile` - `unless system("which phantomjs > /dev/null 2>&1")`... `which` command is not present in Windows, yet I wonder should it be used there at all?

Comment: that's a good point, `which` isn't a windows command this code is not cross platform. i guess i'm the only windows user in the ember community :)

Answer (score 3):

It complains because there is no 'which' command in Windows. Comment out the lines 69-71 in [Rakefile](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/Rakefile#L69) and that should solve the problem.